# How to have a header background image with vh?

Tags: css, image, header, background-image

I'm extremely new to CSS and I'm building my first site through a tutorial. For whatever reason, my header background image won't load. I double checked my image path. I've tried copying and pasting code from similar questions, but nothing appears to work.

Here is the code.

```
header {
background-image: url(img/hero.jpg);
height: 100vh;}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
 <body>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/css/grid.css">
    <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,400i" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Omnifood</title>
</head>
</body>
<header>
        <div class="hero-text-box">
            <h1>Goodbye junk food. Hello super healthy meals.</h1>
            <a href="#">I’m hungry</a>
            <a href="#">Show me more</a>
        </div>

    </header>
```

Comment: can you show your html.

Comment: Bear with me. I am still trying to figure this out. When I add the html, it only lets me put a piece of it in the block. How do I include a larger chunk?

Comment: No need to put the larger chunk but only the copy and paste the HTML for your `header`. The reason is your CSS looks fine to me if the path of image is correct.

Comment: Is that enough?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. As you said you are extremely new to CSS, can you tell me where are you adding this CSS rule? I mean in the `<head></head>` or you are linking a CSS file to the page?

Comment: I added more HTML.

Comment: I'm linking a file to the page.  resources/ccs/stle.css. I also tried linking directly to the image folder but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

html and css looks fine. You may give header a display:block or width:100% but that seems not the reason why it's not working. Do you have a *base* in the *head* of the html? Otherwise it may work with

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
#page {min-height: 100%;}

<body>
  <div id="page">
    HEADER AND CONTENT AND FOOTER
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I started with:

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this kind of issue. Try putting your style between `<head></head>` instead of putting it externally.

Comment: I tried it. Same results. I appreciate the suggestion.